# How to set a default collection in mongoose embedded document schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I set a default collection in a model schema in mongoose.  Using the basic example, how can I have for example a default comment in the comments array.  e.g.

`var defaultComment = {title: 'add your first post'}`

do I do something like this in the definition?  `comments: {type:[Comments], default:defaultComment }`

```
var Comments = new Schema({
    title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : [Comments]
  , meta      : {
        votes : Number
      , favs  : Number
    }
});

mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Mongoose documentation for [Schemas](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html), keys may specify a [default value](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-default). So for your example, one might define the Comments schema as so:

```
var Comments = new Schema({  
    title     : String  
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var CommentsModel = mongoose.model("comments", Comments);
```

Then, store your default comment, and use it as the default value in your BlogPost schema:

```
var defaultComment = new CommentsModel({
    title: "Add your first post"
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : { type: [Comments], default: defaultComment }
  , meta      : {
        votes : Number
      , favs  : Number
    }
});
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: doesn't the line `var CommentsModel = mongoose.model("comments", Comments);` create a new collection in mongodb named comments rather than inferring it to be an embedded collection?

Comment: No, not without explicitly performing a save operation on the `defaultComment` document. In this example, anytime a new BlogPost document is created, the comments array will be automatically populated with one instance of the embedded `defaultComment` document, without creating a `"comments"` collection.